# Delphi MySQL field does not read entire value

Tags: mysql, delphi, zeos

I noticed something wierd in my application, and I cannot find a reason for it.

Basically I have a field which is an identifier field, built from random letters and numbers... For some reason in the database, the full field value is shown(inside phpmyadmin) but when I load the field in delphi XE7, it stops at the first number...
Below are two examples:

database : M7DhPBxh0gqjHFRNYjCbOM3N8GeMTrkwsGSm6hSR6NRPwJsqRUqW0Lq6o4kRhBKgDUkSQvuEgomVFrcYX3OS4YOXAURURQ7pe2nrQXBIPvf9cM3iWFGx9lN0IVl7qC2B0ylgNmwXkaoL3UTOXSgZFHF6YoQwHbrcTaCcGSNU7a4pX9pG5BLICQAXvY8wFNSiVVCPgkS1ZwCz0mPLpfA9soGXA4GWoF8MQ35pEF2h0knmTnzqviJ7Tcovlz

Delphi: M7

database : RkMhDlgyto8rjNCQFv5gJFwLYy6MRlXBe3URGIDAzakzgfhkVlM6NTofI9zLvbqrt3IJTN38v9aJzXHVm56JPuxJ1uw5O2ZMNOrGTvZSv2Lj9trqTpsv8V0rEfwPf8wo2d0LjOsweQHNMhik1rwAIw3uUAJ7fBPv0k2XyWTqgTxSdN3jz3K6W8dOnZZyRITKcDaBBbwT9JEPfXUAs29fp48Cdn7GpTYryZhdXEMCEKJIUxgIkIDuqCySNk

Delphi: RkMhDlgyto8

I simply use the code below to load the table with zeoslib zquery:

```
datalive.achievements.active:=false;
datalive.achievements.SQL.Text:='Select * from achievements where employee_id=:employee_id order by date_of_achievement,description,action_date';
Addparam(datalive.achievements,'employee_id',ftString,datalive.employees.FieldByName('employee_id').AsString);
datalive.achievements.Active:=true;
```

Is there any reason why this would happen?

**UPDATE:**

I have just noticed, it happen without any numbers aswell... Example is below:

Delphi: GJThADDBXPpqCkWE

database : GJThADDBXPpqCkWEItmtfRtCuRsXnRPlKxGqzODrAqIXGuzSZ

Comment: Do you get the same if you open the database table using Delphi's DBExpress TSqlConnection, etc?

Comment: Im not sure how to use those... But what I did notice @MartynA is that if i delete the mysql field and recreate it, it does seem to solve the problem... but later it happens to other fields aswell...

Comment: seems a zeos bug to me , what version are you using?

Comment: I agree with @whosrdaddy as it's unlikely to be a problem with the MySql server and Delphi apps don't have this kind of problem with other db components.  DBExpress is v. simple to use - worth spending a couple of hours with it to get the idea.  At least then you could pin problems on Zeos, if that's where they arise.

Comment: Cool @MartynA I will have a look into it... But if it is zeos, how can it only happen to 1 field at a time... and when I recreate the same field with the same values, the problem disappears?

Comment: *how can it only happen* - if we knew what the bug was, we'd know.  If you think changing something in the IDE fixes it, keep a record copy of the DFM (text version) when you fix it, and then compare it to the current version of it when the problem appears.